# presentModalViewController problem - iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, presentmodalviewcontroller

I am using custom tabbar without the tabbar controller. When I try to add the viewController using

```
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

edit: changed to presentsModalViewController.

which is for MFMailComposeViewController it works fine but it also removes the tabbar when I dismiss it.

For solution I had to present the controller on appDelegate.viewController like:

```
[APPDELEGATE.navigationController presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

edit: changed to presentsModalViewController.

This works fine and don't remove the tabbar. But the issue is when  the iphone get locked after getting idle and I try to present the controller using this:

```
[APPDELEGATE.navigationController presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

edit: changed to presentsModalViewController.

It does not work.
In debug mode the code is executing but it is not presenting the viewController.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it myself. The problem was I was reallocating the navigation controller in the

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if you copied the Code right then you use
`[APPDELEGATE.viewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`
instead of
`[APPDELEGATE.viewController presentsModalViewController:YOURVIEWController Animated:YES];` on the second call